# In wget how could I save a webpage to current date?

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a htm page, with these options:

```
wget --no-check-cert http://sedar.com/new_docs/all_new_mf_filings_en.htm --directory-prefix=SEDAR --convert-links -output-document=date +%F_%T.htm
```

But all I get is: a file w/o extension and a name like this: utput-document=date
What am I doing wrong?

Also I am in Windows command line and would like to grab the .htm file and rename it to the current date, eg.: 20160808.htm (The date format doesn't really matter it can be in any kind of order.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-O` to specify the file name

```
wget  url -O filename
```

Here for this you may use the following

```
mkdir -p SEDAR
wget --no-check-cert http://sedar.com/new_docs/all_new_mf_filings_en.htm  --convert-links -O `date +SEDAR/%Y%m%d.htm`
```

For people using windows power shell following should work (have not tested)

```
 sh -c "wget --no-check-cert sedar.com/new_docs/all_new_mf_filings_en.htm --convert-links -O `date +SEDAR/%Y%m%d.htm`"
```

Comment: Now I end up with a file named `date w/o extension...Do I need anything else besides wget and a command line?

Comment: No you dont need anything else.
Are you using bash or zsh.fish as terminal ?

and dont ignore the backticks('`')

Comment: using windows power shell you must be able to run it as 

sh -c "wget --no-check-cert http://sedar.com/new_docs/all_new_mf_filings_en.htm  --convert-links -O \`date +SEDAR/%Y%m%d.htm\`"